# Phase noise measurement with an IQ mixer

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, signal-processing, microwaves, noise

I have a question regarding a measurement scheme of phase noise that I'm trying to implement. The idea is that I have two identical signal generators (I actually do) that generate a sinusoidal voltage signal $V(t) = V_a(t) \sin\left(2\pi\nu + \phi(t)\right)$ where $V_a(t)$ is the amplitude, $\nu$ the frequency (I'll just assume that this is implemented perfectly for now) and $\phi(t)$ the phase.

Now ideally both the amplitude and phase would be static values, but in practice they are both subjected to noise (think thermal noise, 1/f noise, etc). In general this noise has a vanishing mean, so I could for example write $V_a(t) = V_a + \delta V_a(t)$, $\phi(t) = \phi + \delta \phi(t)$ where $\left<V_a(t)\right> = V_a$ and $\left<\phi(t)\right> = \phi$. With this the signals produced by the generators become
$V(t) = \left(V_a+\delta V_a(t)\right) \sin\left(2\pi\nu + \phi + \delta\phi(t)\right)$.

Now, the purpose of my investigation is to characterize $\delta\phi(t)$: I am trying to find its power spectral density. The way I do this is by measuring the voltage signal in a time series and using (discrete) Fourier transforms to find the voltage spectral density and then the power spectral density. However, in general the noise is quite hard to distinguish when it competes with the actual time alternating part due to $\nu$. So to get this out, we use a trick: using an IQ mixer with an LO and RF signal at the same frequency, we use the downconverted signal at their difference ($=0$) frequency to get a DC signal, which is actually slightly time varying due to the phase noise.

Great! So then we would have a signal of the type (setting $\phi = 0$) for convenience) $V(t) = \left(V_a+\delta V_a(t)\right) \sin\left(\delta\phi(t)\right)$.

But here is where my question comes in. We only want to measure the phase noise, not the amplitude noise, and I don't understand how this is achieved. In the scheme we use, one uses an IQ mixer (inputs LO and RF) with outputs I and Q, but we terminate Q and only use the output from I. Somehow this gives a signal in which the amplitude oscillations are not longer relevant. Personally, I don't see this however, and I can't really find any documentation on the whole I-Q picture that's helping me out there.

So my question is, how does using only the I channel from the mixer make it so that our output signal is unaffected by the amplitude noise, and that we only look at phase noise?

Comment: $I^2+Q^2$ gives you the amplitude, of you want it. You can also measure the amplitude of each signal independently and use that to normalize the calculation, which will throw that noise term out. Using just one of the two quadrature signals won't do that for you.

Comment: @CuriousOne Okay, so you're saying that if I simply downconvert to the DC signal and terminate the Q-port (so I only look at the I part, right?) I'll have a signal that contains both the phase noise and the amplitude noise? I'm doing this as a part of an orientation in a new lab, and my supervisor made some argument about how you are insensitive to the amplitude noise if you measure along the I axis in the phase diagram, which I didn't completely follow. But if I understand you correctly, it's also just wrong. How would normalizing throw out the noise term though? Because noise/amp = approx 0?

Comment: Okay so I just talked to him to ask about this, and what he says is that we set our phase so that the mean value of the signal is along the Q-axis, making us insensitive to the amplitude noise. I don't really see this yet 100% but I will think about it for a moment.

Comment: If the amplitude noise is very large, it's wrong, but usually it's not large. The other question is... is your second oscillator part of a loop? Are you already phase locked? In that case your supervisor might be right. I would have to think about that. As a general note... it's never a good idea to downconvert to DC, better do this measurement on an IF frequency and use a spectrum around that frequency, otherwise you are folding the DC drift and 1/f spectrum of your DC amplifier in (or use a really, really good DC system...).

Comment: Okay so the measurement setup is as given in this image http://i.imgur.com/Ph0AwW6.png. The idea is that they are connected to the same clock so that their phases are equal, but in practice there is still some offset so I use the voltmeter to monitor this and just adjust the relative phase. The amplifier is just for some gain basically and the AWGs and FPGA are to measure the time trace. And that is a good point, about the 1/f.

Comment: Also, I should add that what we actually do with the voltmeter is look at the voltage, and try to get it as close to 0 as possible. I feel like this is probably crucial in terms of the I-Q diagram and some taylor expansion, but its not exactly clear to me.

Comment: I see... I would still have to think about it, but I would agree with you that this setup is sensitive to amplitude (modulation) noise. I would monitor that by measuring   $I^2+Q^2$, if possible.

Comment: Right, so perhaps if I measure that I'll find that it is incredibly small compared to the phase noise, which would then sort of explain why the measurements almost precisely reproduce the spectrum given by the manufacturer in the datasheet. That was kind of the argument I was given for that this scheme works (not satisfactory but not easy to dispute).

Comment: If your oscillators are any good, that argument is correct.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I don't really see it from the math. That's what I'm kind of looking for, the expression for the I-output where I can see the dependencies on the noise.

Comment: Oh, and I see now that perhaps my wording was vague. The argument I got was that it reproduces what the datasheet says, not that the amplitude noise is small and that it therefore doesn't show up. He said that it'll factor in in a different order than the phase noise, which I can't find mathematically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36068/discussion-between-curiousone-and-user129412).

Comment: A well behaved (single frequency) oscillator's AM is noise is usually much smaller than its phase noise because the positive feedback generating the oscillation mechanism saturates the underlying active circuit (amplifier). If you are still worried about any residual AM noise corrupting your phase noise measurement then you must employ a bandpass limiter (very high gain amplifier + filter) following the oscillator.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for the comment. I have to say I'm quite new to this, so I'm not entirely sure how that bandpass limiter would help with this. You try to amplify the amplitude noise, so that you can take it out?

Comment: On the contrary. An "ideal" bandpass limiter REMOVES all AM noise, because the output amplitude becomes independent of the input amplitude, only phase modulation passes through.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, I see yes. Interesting to take into account.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this post?

Comment: @DanielSank For my own purposes, I would say no, it has been solved to satisfaction. But not in a way that I could use to write a nice answer to the original question.

Comment: Hey, sorry I never got back to you. I can answer this if you're still interested.